# How to create a hierarchical tree structure of a MongoDB data set with help of Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a hierarchical dataset with 4 levels of hierarchical as you can see in the image below. I have already imported the data into MongoDB, as you can see below in the example extract.

My goal is to display this data in a tree component I found here: https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component

This lib want the data in JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'root1',
    isExpanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'child1'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'child2'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The "name" should be connected to "preferredName" and "id" to "codedName", but how should I relate the parent with the child nodes and where should I do it, already in MongoDB or after in an object in Javascript (the data set has approx 50.000 unique 8 digits codes)? What I have is the 8 digits id structure as you can see example plus the 4 levels connected to each unique 8 digits code:
13000000 Segment
13010000 Main Group
13010100 Group
13010101 Commodity Class

[image: http://wiki.eclass.eu/w/images/1/12/EClass_tree_structure_example_01.JPG]

MongoDB example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c106f886102c16f0489a01"),
    "mkKeyword" : "0",
    "mkSubclass" : "1",
    "level" : "1",
    "definition" : "Services for the development of a product basically on the basis of service contracts or contract development",
    "preferredName" : "Development (Service)",
    "codedName" : "13000000",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c106f886102c16f0489a02"),
    "mkKeyword" : "0",
    "mkSubclass" : "1",
    "level" : "2",
    "definition" : "Total or partial service for product developments",
    "preferredName" : "Concept development",
    "codedName" : "13010000",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c106f886102c16f0489a03"),
    "mkKeyword" : "0",
    "mkSubclass" : "1",
    "level" : "3",
    "definition" : "Total or partial service for product developments",
    "preferredName" : "Feasibility analysis",
    "codedName" : "13010100",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c106f886102c16f0489a04"),
    "mkKeyword" : "0",
    "mkSubclass" : "0",
    "level" : "4",
    "definition" : "Sub-group (4th level) for objects that cannot be classified into other specified sub-groups in the existing structure, but that are classified to their parent-class on the 3rd level",
    "preferredName" : "Feasibility analysis (unspecified)",
    "codedName" : "13010190",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
const EclassSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        codedName: { type: String, min: 10, max: 10 },
        preferredName: { type: String, max: 80 },
        definition: { type: String, max: 1023 },
        level: { type: String, min: 1, max: 1 },
        mkSubclass: { type: String, min: 1, max: 1 },
        mkKeyword: { type: String, min: 1, max: 1 }
    });
```